# Could math expressions be effectively written if the order of operations was different?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We're all familiar with PEMDAS, the general order of operations. However, I was thinking that the order of operations seems to be a way of organizing our syntax, rather than an actual mathematical reason for doing it this way.

Take, for example, Division and Addition. As far as I'm aware, there's no real reason division happens before addition, other than that's the convention that we chose when we wrote the problem down in order to communicate our ideas.

My question is, are there any studies that investigate if the entire order of operations be completely randomized and we would still be able to write down any math problem? If there are, is there any evidence that other cultures have taken different orders of operations?

Comment: "As far as I'm aware, there's no real reason division happens before addition."  Why do you say that?  Try it in the reverse order to see....

Comment: Order of operations is just convention that avoids many parentheses. The underlying mathematics is independent of those conventions. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation for a convention that requires no parentheses.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Obviously, just doing the same problem in a different order would result in a different answer. I'm talking about "if the entire world was taught with PEMADS, would we still be able to write down any arbitrary math problem that we can with PEMDAS?"

Comment: @duper51 Yes - just use parentheses to make things perfectly explicit.

Comment: @duper51 PEMADS in particular doesn't work because it would be extremely awkward for an operation (multipliation) and its inverse to not have the same precedence.

Comment: @redroid That doesn't mean it doesn't work, just that it's annoying.

Comment: Yes: you can write down anything with any order of operations you like, so long as parentheses are first. However, putting division separate from multiplication makes your notation much messier - for example, it is no longer the case that $a + b/c = a + bc^{-1}$.

Comment: So since the first mathematical expressions were written, the order of operations was always PEMDAS? I find it somewhat amazing that since these ideas were developed all over the world at around the same time, the order remained the same... Is there an explicit reason for this?

Comment: @duper51 "Since the first mathematical expressions were written, the order of operations was always PEMDAS" Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @NoahSchweber well that's why I was asking... Did the order of operations that we know today as PEMDAS get used universally? Or is it just something that started as a convention in one part of the world that eventually propagated elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conventions like PEMDAS are used to let us parse a priori ambiguous expressions like "$2+3\times 5$." However, we could avoid any reliance on such conventions by just ... not writing ambiguous expressions! Parentheses let us clearly express what we mean: e.g. $$(2+3)\times 5$$ or $$2+(3\times 5)$$ as the case may be.

Perhaps more snappily, **the only part of PEMDAS which is important is the "P" at the beginning**: the role parentheses serve is exactly to indicate order of precedence, and any additional conventions are just window dressing.

---

It might help make the above feel more natural to observe that PEMDAS itself (and its variants) is really just a **rule for inserting parentheses** into an expression which lacks them. Consider for example $$2^6\times 8+3\times 5^4.$$ PEMDAS adds parentheses to this as follows:

- The highest-precedence operation occurring in the expression is exponentiation, so we put parentheses around each instance of that; this gets us $$(2^6)\times 8 + 3\times (5^4).$$
- Next up is multiplication, so we put parentheses around those; this gets us $$((2^6)\times 8)+(3\times (5^4)).$$

And that's totally unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that PEMDAS is essentially a shorthand about organizing syntax, but one aspect that hasn't been mentioned is that disambiguating expressions is necessary because our operators use "infix" syntax - that is, they appear between the operands they apply to.

There are alternatives that avoid this problem, such as prefix (also called "Polish") notation. In prefix notation, operators appear in front of *both* operands, such as $+ 2 \space 2 = 4$. You can nest such expressions like so: $ \times + 2 \space 2 \space 3 =\times (+ 2 \space 2) \space 3 = 12$. "Reverse Polish" is similar, but with the operands at the back, e.g. $2 \space 2 + \space 3 \times $

So long as the number of operands each function takes is fixed, (so not an operator like $ \Sigma $) then the expression is always unambigious even without any parantheses. This is very useful in applications like computer progamming, because it simplifies the manipulations required to actually work out which operations need to happen and in which order.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we reversed the order of addition and multiplication:

So to do $3 + 4\times 5$ the old way we do $4\times 5=20$ first and $3+20=23$ second.

But to do $3+ 4\times 5$ the new way we do $3+4=7$ first and $7\times 5 = 35$ second.

So can we write the old "concept" using new convention.  Sure.  Just put the $4\times 5$ in parethesis to force us to do them first.  $3 + (4 \times 5)=3+20=23$.

You know, you could just as easily have asked how can we write the "new" concept using the old convention.  And the answer is the same.  Put the $3+4$ in parenthesis to force us to do them first.  $(3+4)\times 5 = 7\times 5=35$.

.....

Which is basically what everyone else said.  I want to point out the *intuitive* reason we do multiplication first.

No matter what notation we use multiplication "distributes" over addition.  $a\times (b+c) = (a\times b) + (a\times c)$.  But the other way isn't true $a+ (b\times c) \ne (a+b)\times (a+c)$.  As such multiplication is more "fundamental" than addition and products tend to "clump" together in "atoms".  For long equations with simplifications and distributions it just makes things simplier.

Imagine trying to write a simple expression $(x+2)^2 + 3x = x^2 + 7x + 4$ with the new methodology.  $(x+2)^2 +(3\times x) = ((x^2) + (4\times x) + (2^2)) + (3\times x)=(x^2) + (4\times x) + (2^2) + (3\times x) = (x^2) + (7\times x) + 4$.

Its doable but it's a mess.